# why Exception has occurred. Unknown signal when runing `delete[] p;`

Tags: c++

when I runing this code by the time the last step. it return this message

> Exception has occurred.
> Unknown signal

```cpp
int main()
{
    int n = 4;
    int *p = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = 2 * i +1;
    
    for (int *q = p + n; p < q; p++){
        cout << *p << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;
    char *s = (char *)p; //强制转换，int型占的字节数时char型的四倍，因此这个s的长度需要重新计算
    char ch = 'A';
    int n2 = n * sizeof(int) / sizeof(char);  //
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        s[i] = ch + i;
    
    for (char *r = s + n2; s < r; s++){
        //遍历s
        cout << *s;
    }
    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to solve this error.

Comment: `delete` only works on a value that was returned from `new`. Once you do `p++`, p is no longer that value.

Answer (score 2):

After you have assigned the result of `new[]` to `p`, your 2nd `for` loop is changing where `p` is pointing, thus making the subsequent `delete[] p` invalid. You must give `delete[]` a pointer to the same memory address that `new[]` had returned.

Change your `for` loop to use a different variable to iterate the array:

```
for (int *j = p, *q = p + n; j < q; j++){
    cout << *j << '\t';
}
```